# Count number of character occurrences from input text file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, flatmap, bigdata

How to convert flatMap of a text file to flatMap of characters? I have to count of occurrences of each character from a text file. What approach to take after following code?

```
val words = readme.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).collect()
```

Comment: I'll bet you a pint that running this serially outside of Spark will run quicker for almost any size of input. Is this an assignment? And if you're just counting characters, why are you splitting on space first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to convert each `String` into its representing characters, you need an additional `flatMap`:

```
val characters = lines.flatMap(_.split(" ")).flatMap(_.toCharArray)

scala> val lines = Array("hello world", "yay more lines")
lines: Array[String] = Array(hello world, yay more lines)

scala> lines.flatMap(_.split(" ")).flatMap(_.toCharArray)
res3: Array[Char] = Array(h, e, l, l, o, w, o, r, l, d, y, a, y, m, o, r, e, l, i, n, e, s)
```

Although this is a Scala console, it will work the same on an `RDD`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in `char`'s then I think you probably want to count `spaces ' '` too

```
val chars = readme.flatMap(line => line.toCharArray)

// but if you dont want to count spaces too,
// val chars = readme.flatMap(line => line.toCharArray.filter(_ != ' '))

val charsCount = chars
  .map(c => (c, 1))
  .reduceByKey((i1: Int, i2: Int) => i1 + i2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val txt = a.getClass.getResourceAsStream("/a.txt")
val txtFile = File.createTempFile("a", "txt")
txtFile.deleteOnExit()
ByteStreams.copy(txt, Files.newOutputStreamSupplier(txtFile))
val tokenized = sc.textFile(txtFile.toString).flatMap(_.split(' ')) 
val char = tokenized.flatMap(_.toCharArray)
```